# Semantic UI - Accordion - Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Help me please, i have this libs:

```html
<title>Semantic UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/semantic.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/components/accordion.js"></script>
```

and this is the html code:

```html
<div class="ui container">
        <div class="ui styled accordion">
          <div class="title">
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            Hello
          </div>
          <div class="content">
            contenido 1
          </div>
         </div>
 </div>
```

and js:

```html
<script>
        $('.ui.accordion').accordion();
      </script>
```

What am I missing to work fine this element ? Am I need some scripts to add ? I have a browser console error:

TypeError: $('.ui.accordion').accordion is not a function. (In '$('.ui.accordion').accordion()', '$('.ui.accordion').accordion' is undefined)

Comment: Maybe you can create a JSFiddle for this? That makes debugging easier. Have you used your browser console to see javascript errors?

Comment: TypeError: $('.ui.accordion').accordion is not a function. (In '$('.ui.accordion').accordion()', '$('.ui.accordion').accordion' is undefined) this is my browser console error.

Answer (score 1):

you're script tags have the typo for the attribute `src` on your script tag. In your example, its spelled `scr`, so the page is never actually loading your libraries. So change:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script scr="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/components/accordion.js"></script>
```

TO:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/components/accordion.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put accordion module.

Simple add after semantic.min.js:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.4/components/accordion.js"></script>
```